# Pointing a dynamic table cell to an editable screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a list of entities that will be displayed in table cells. I want to allow a user to view/edit the details of each entity by tapping on that cell and going to a screen that has a form with the details of that entity filled in.

I'm wondering if there is a way to tie the ID of each entity to its cell so that when the cell is tapped, I can retrieve that entity and fill in the form?  This may not be the best approach as well, so please let me know if my idea to handle this is wrong...  However, is there a way to display this form based on the cell selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I get you right:
The concept should be as simple as that :
Your tableview is backed by an array that contains your entities.
If a tableviewcell is tapped you get an indexPath as a parameter from the delegate method called.
This indexPath has a row property that priecicly matches the index in your array of the entity that is show by the cell that was tapped.
You can then retrieve the entity for the array using the index and pass this entity over to your detail screen

Comment: +1, good answer, pls, try giving code in your answers, it always helps.

Comment: Yes. Your right. I was just on my mobile phone and could not resist dropping some short lines :)

Comment: Yep... I can't believe this was so over my head. I'm so used to stateless web development that I don't think through these things so clearly!